# how to create a link to dial a phone number?

Tags: html, call

good time to all friends

I am going to create a link so that when the user clicks on that link a contact number will be taken. Note that I don't mean how to create this link inside my website, because with the 'tel 'attribute of the a tag in the 'href' he did it on the internal pages of the site.

```
<a href="tel:1234567890">Number</a>
```

I don't mean this code above!

What I mean is that I can create a link and, for example, put that link in the Instagram story, and when the user clicks on the link, he will be referred to the contact number on his phone screen and he can call.

for example:
https://sl.inoti.com/r/04hm62

Comment: Instargram does not allow for non-web related links

Comment: instagram is a example

Comment: in that case your question is poorly worded